# Should command handler contains services or services contains commands?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am trying to follow the CQRS pattern but I dont know who should contain who. Like should I inject application services on command handlers or is it the other way around?

here is the example. I am injecting service to command handler. and use the service inside the **Execute** method of the **CreatProductCategoryCommandHandler**

```
public CreateProductCategoryCommandHandler(ICategoryService categoryService)
{
    _categoryService = categoryService;
}
```

or do I even need services when I have command handlers?

Answer (score 8):

What is a "service" in your definition?

Usually, a service (e.g., domain service, application service) works without (the notion of) a command handler, while the command handler needs the service to handle the command.  Therefore, the service needs to be injected into the command handler, and not the other way around.

Comment: ah, ok.  FWIW, IMO command handlers are actually application services.

Comment: so you mean that I am just duplicating the work? having another category service? another question, where should I commit my changes to database. [in entity framework, calling the SaveChanges()] in command handler or category service?

Comment: to elaborate my question. should I commit my changes to database in command handler(injecct IUnitOfWork) or category service which has reference to IUnitOfWork?

Comment: yes, I would say so (duplicate work).  Our command handlers load the entities from the database/repository, call the respective methods on the entities, and then persist the changes to the database again.

Comment: Here's a typical command handler as the ones we use in production: https://github.com/JEEventStore/JEECQRS-Quickstart-Sample/blob/master/ejb/src/main/java/org/jeecqrs/example/quickstart/application/billing/PayInvoiceCommandHandler.java  It's in Java, but you'll notice the pattern. (in case  you are not familiar with Java EE/EJBs: the `handle` function is a transaction boundary (the app container starts a transaction before calling `handle` and commits the transaction when `handle` returns)

Comment: but did you find yourself needing to create like let say (on the link you provided) IInvoiceService and inject it in your command handler? or you will just do all logic inside handler without creating IInvoice service?

Comment: We just do the application logic in command handlers, which is essentially loading domain state from database, tell the domain to change its state, persist new state.    More complicated logic that originates in the *domain* is done in domain services -- these are created/injected by the command handlers in that case.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I learned a lot from you. I guess I have to grab the Blue Book and read Domain Services :)

Comment: @AlexanderLanger This is quite old, but I got confused by your answer and comment. Having `CommandHandler` and `Repositories` is ok, but every now and then, the business logic is a bit too complex (ie builder pattern on a specific object), so we added the `Service` layer. The initial idea was to inject the `Service` (receiving a `Repository` as dependency) to the `CommandHandler` (or maybe the Service AND the `Repository`, although it would be cleaner just one). Your answer seems to corroborate that, but didn't understand your last comment where the dependency is the oposote, mind elaborating?

Comment: @lowercase00 I think we have the same understanding: The command handler depends on the service (therefore, with dependency injection, the service is injected into the command handler).  My last comment was meant to address the question "Like should I inject application services on command handlers or is it the other way around?" of the OP.